# putty ssh client stop responding frequently in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssh, putty, safe-mode

I'm using windows 7, on a machine with celeron processor and 512 MB ram
It takes too much time even to open a folder in windows explorer.

I connect to the internet with a GPRS modem. When I tried to connect with  a remote linux machine using putty ssh, the client stop responding just after 2 or 3 minutes. 
When I try again to connect putty client doesn't seem to connect.

I tried to make it work using Safe mode with networking but the issue there is that the GPRS modem is not detected. The modem is USB data card.

Is it possible to load modem USB driver in safe mode from windows 7 
or how else could I possibly connect with my hardware via ssh?

Comment: Your system does not meet the requirements for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

> celeron processor and 512 MB ram windows 7

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/system-requirements) says that Win7 needs at least 1 GB RAM. Personally I would not even try with less than two.

> internet with GPRS modem

Ouch. GPRS can have *huge* roundtrip times if not 3G. Try to ping the linux server when putty gets unresponsive. A likely cause would be big downloads like Windows Update etc. These can use up to 100% of a slow internet pipe so there is no "room" for your SSH or ping packets to arrive in a timely manner.

> any other possibility to connect with remote machine via ssh

A Linux based OS would be a possible alternative.